# Create a function for counting rows from any table

Tags: sql, sql-server, function, dynamic

I have this user-defined function:

```
 CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[COUNT_ROWS_TABLE]()
 RETURNS TINYINT
 AS
 BEGIN
      DECLARE @ROW_COUNT TINYINT
      SELECT @ROW_COUNT = COUNT(*) FROM EMPLOYEE
      RETURN @ROW_COUNT
 END
 GO
```

The problem is it only works for the table `[dbo].[EMPLOYEE]` and I don't want to Copy-Paste this function for every table on my database.

My attempt so far:

```
 CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[COUNT_ROWS_TABLE](@TABLE_NAME VARCHAR(50))
 RETURNS TINYINT
 AS
 BEGIN
      DECLARE @SQL_COMMAND NVARCHAR(100)
      DECLARE @PARAM NVARCHAR(50)
      DECLARE @ROW_COUNT TINYINT
      SET @SQL_COMMAND = N'SELECT @RESULT = COUNT(*) FROM ' + @TABLE_NAME
      SET @PARAM = N'@RESULT TINYINT OUTPUT'
      EXEC SP_EXECUTESQL @SQL_COMMAND, @PARAM, @RESULT = @ROW_COUNT OUTPUT
      RETURN @ROW_COUNT
 END
 GO
```

That code does not work because it doesn't allow those statements inside a function.
It works inside a stored procedure, though, but only if I `PRINT` the variable rather than `RETURN` it.

I need it to be a function, since I need to call it on an `IF` statement.

Any thoughts on how to achieve this? Thank you.

Comment: Tinyint? So none of your tables will ever contain more than 255 rows?!?

Comment: @Philip Kelley Yes, because it's for PERSONAL use only (and it's a small database anyway). 

All my tables would around 100-200 rows... 230 rows tops. 
So, I don't want to use an unnecessary (and greater) type in this situation.

Thank you for the suggestion.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use like below

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[COUNT_ROWS_TABLE](@TABLE_NAME VARCHAR(50))
 RETURNS TINYINT
AS
BEGIN
DECLARE @ROW_COUNT TINYINT
SELECT @ROW_COUNT = SUM(b.rows) 
FROM SYS.TABLES a INNER JOIN sys.partitions b ON b.OBJECT_ID = a.OBJECT_ID
WHERE a.is_ms_shipped = 0 AND b.index_id IN (1,0)
        and a.name=@TABLE_NAME
GROUP BY a.name

RETURN @ROW_COUNT
END
GO
```

Comment: +1 but why alias with a and b instead of, I don't know, t and p? You can also simplify with just `RETURN (SELECT SUM(b.rows...) FROM ...);` instead of bothering with a local variable.

Answer (score 0):

For this kind of Query where you pass an object name as a parameter, you will need to use Dynamic Sql, but since you are only returning total number of rows this is achievable using sys schema cataloge views with use of Dynamic sql,  you cannot use Dynamic Sql inside a UDF definition.

### A Stored Procedure with an OUTPUT parameter

Here is what you would need to do.....

```
 CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[COUNT_ROWS_TABLE]
  @TABLE_NAME SYSNAME,
  @Count      INT      OUTPUT
 AS
 BEGIN
   SET NOCOUNT ON;

      DECLARE @Sql NVARCHAR(MAX);

      SET @Sql  = N'SELECT @Count = COUNT(*) FROM ' + QUOTENAME(@TABLE_NAME)

  EXECUTE sp_executesql @Sql
                     , N'@Count INT OUTPUT'
                     , @Count OUTPUT

 END
 GO
```

### Function using with sys schema

```
 CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[COUNT_ROWS_TABLE]
  (
    @TableName SYSNAME
   )
 RETURNS INT
 AS
 BEGIN
   DECLARE @Row_Count INT;

    SELECT @Row_Count = i.rowcnt 
    FROM sysindexes AS i
    INNER JOIN sysobjects AS o  ON i.id = o.id 
    WHERE i.indid < 2  AND OBJECTPROPERTY(o.id, 'IsMSShipped') = 0
     AND o.NAME = @TableName

  RETURN @Row_Count;

END
```

Comment: (1) I would never do a count against the table directly. Why? All this will do is block, much less impact to query the DMVs/catalog views. (2) I like your second query better, but please, please, PLEASE stop using sysindexes/sysobjects. These are BACKWARD COMPATIBILITY VIEWS that have been DEPRECATED. (It also doesn't deal with partitioned tables.)